# Word VBA: Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)' when calling FileDialog.Execute

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using Office365 under Windows 10.

I am trying to invoke the Save dialog programmatically and then save the open document.

Minimal testcase:

```
Private Sub TestSave()
    If Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show Then
        Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Execute
    End If
End Sub
```

(For the real code, I am programmatically setting the default filename and filter, but these aren't needed to show the problem.)

However, on the call to `.Execute`, I get an error popup:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'
>
> Command failed

What does this mean?  How do I fix it?  (The Help button in the error dialog doesn't lead to any page that explains the error.)

This seems to be happening regardless of what folder I try to save to.

Comment: `Show` will execute when the user confirms the dialog box, according to what the user chooses (OK or Cancel). If you want to display the dialog box then handle what happens afterwards, use `Display`, then `Execute` if the conditions you want are met.

Comment: @CindyMeister 1. How can `Show` execute when the user confirms the dialog, given that `Show` is needed to display the dialog in the first place?  2. `Display` doesn't seem to exist as I try.  "Method or data member not found"

Comment: Furthermore, I've found something weirder.  It works when I start a new document from my template.  But not when I open my template for editing.  (Yes, there are reasons that I need it to work in the latter scenario.)

Comment: A, sorry, I was thinking about Word's internal Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs). Take a look at that and see if it's more useful.

Comment: And research *what* both kinds of dialog *return* for values. I'm on a mobile device at the moment and can't look at anything, but as I recall the return values are numerical, not boolean, in both cases. Possibly, the one you're using is not returning what you think in certain situations... Also, look at the "Built-in dialog box arguments" (search term) for Word's FileSaveAs which allows setting and reading of dialog box settings.

Comment: Looking at the Help for the topic the sample there uses `If .Show = -1 Then` - you might try that.

Comment: @CindyMeister I have stepped through the code, and thereby confirmed that `.Execute` is being called when I expect it to, so know the issue has nothing to do with the return semantics of `.Show`.